# Converting UTC time to Unix without changing default timezone

Tags: php, date

I'm having a problem where I'm dealing with another server in UTC time. Our procedure here is to always convert timestamps to Unix before sending times to our company's app to use. The problem in this instance is that we're dealing with a third party server as well, which is in a different time zone.

```
date("U", strtotime($UTCtime))
```

converts to Unix and, since there is no specified time zone offset, uses the time zone in the php.ini file. I know this type of question is well documented on stackoverflow. What I'm having a harder time with is that the most common accepted answers deal with changing the default timezone in php.ini or other PHP functions, which will not work for us for a number of reasons.

How can I, **only in this case**, tell date() to see $UTCtime as UTC time?

Comment: Unix Timestamps are always UTC. You just need to know the timezone to get the local time.

Comment: Why doesn't [date_default_timezone_set](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php) work for you?

Comment: It does, actually. My original understanding was that date_default_timezone_set changed something universally, but I now (between when I asked this and now) understand the change is temporary and ends when the script ends.